# Self Join Several Tables Removed

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

I have 4 tables: `resources`, `feature_resources`, `features`, and `feature_types`.

A `resource` has many `features` (using `feature_resources` as a join table) and each `feature` has a `feature_type`.

I need to check if a particular `resource` has both `features` with both `RESOURCE_TYPE` and `LIBRARY`.

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
SELECT * FROM resources
INNER JOIN feature_resources ON feature_resources.resource_id = resources.id
INNER JOIN features AS f1 ON f1.id = feature_resources.feature_id
INNER JOIN features AS f2 ON f2.id = feature_resources.feature_id
INNER JOIN feature_types AS ft1 ON ft1.id = f1.feature_type_id
INNER JOIN feature_types AS ft2 ON ft2.id = f2.feature_type_id
WHERE ft1.value = 'RESOURCE_TYPE' 
AND ft2.value = 'LIBRARY'
```

I think the issue is that the `feature.id` will be different, only the `resource.id` will be the same. I tried the above code with `LEFT JOIN` and it still did not work.

My current solution is a subquery approach:

```
SELECT "resources".* 
FROM "resources" 
INNER JOIN feature_resources ON feature_resources.resource_id = resources.id 
INNER JOIN features AS featureTwo ON featureTwo.id = feature_resources.feature_id 
INNER JOIN feature_types AS featureTypeTwo ON featureTwo.feature_type_id = featureTypeTwo.id 
WHERE "resources"."id" 
  IN 
  (SELECT "resources"."id" 
  FROM "resources" 
  INNER JOIN feature_resources ON feature_resources.resource_id = resources.id 
  INNER JOIN features AS featureOne ON feature_resources.feature_id = featureOne.id 
  INNER JOIN feature_types AS featureTypeOne ON featureOne.feature_type_id = 
  featureTypeOne.id 
  WHERE (featureOne.string_value = 'ZONE') 
  AND (featureTypeOne.value = 'RESOURCE_TYPE')) 
AND (featureTypeTwo.value = 'LIBRARY')
```

This works, just curious if there is a way to use inner joins rather than sub queries.

I'm using postgres, but any generic SQL answer would be interesting to see.

**DATA**

resources:

```
| id | description |
| 1  | Office      |
```

feature_resources:

```
| resource_id | feature_id |
|     1       |     1      |
|     1       |     2      |
```

features:

```
| id | string_value | feature_type_id |
| 1  |  Zone        |       1         |
| 2  |   nil        |       2         |
```

feature_types:

```
| id | value          |
|  1 |  RESOURCE_TYPE |
|  2 |  LIBRARY       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use aggregates to determine which resources you need:
something like:

```
select resources.id, resources.description 
from
  resources
join 
 feature_resources
on 
  resources.id = feature_resources.resource_id 
join
  features 
on
  feature_resources.features_id = features.id
join 
  feature_types
on 
  features.feature_type_id = feature_types.id
where 
  feature_types.value in ( 'RESOURCE_TYPE', 'LIBRARY' )
group by 
  resources.id, resources.description 
having 
  count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Would this ensure that I had one 'RESOURCE_TYPE' and one 'LIBRARY' or would it be possible that if a resource had 2 'RESOURCE_TYPE' entries this would still be marked as valid?

Comment: as written, any 2 - but you could go with `count(distinct feature_types.id)` if duplicates are possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
  r.* 
from 
  feature_resources fr

  inner join resources r on
    r.id = fr.resource_id

  inner join features f on 
    f.id = fr.feature_id

  inner join feature_types ft on
    ft.id = f.feature_type_id
where 
  ft.value in ('resource_type', 'library')
group by
  r.id
having
  count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that `column "r.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I think we have to change the `group by` a little

Comment: Just add `r.id` to the group by clause and remove `fr.resource_id`